# How can I update fields on unsupported transaction types such as Bill with user event suitescript on netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I want to update a field on Bill record type with user event script but i can not find it on Applies to section on Script Deployment. 
Can you please help me about that?

Answer (score 2):

you should see `Vendor Bill` in the Applies to section. `Bill` itself won't be available.